# Arithmetic, geometric and harmonic means: adding a constant to data values

Tags: calculus, arithmetic, means

If to each observation $x_i$ we add a constant $c$, then $\frac{\sum(x_i+c)}{n}=\bar{x}+c$

Can we find an expression for the new geometric mean as a function of the old geometric mean? What about the harmonic mean?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The function will depend on individual $x_i$ for GM or HM. Now if you were multiplying by a positive constant, the expression would be simple ;)

Comment: Let $a=2$, $b=2$, $c=1$, and let $a'=1$, $b'=4$, $c=1$. The geometric mean of $a$ and $b$ is the same as the geometric mean of $a'$ and $b'$. However, the geometric mean of $a+1$ and $b+1$ is $3$, while the geometric mean of $a'+1$ and $b'+1$ is $\sqrt{10}\ne 3$. So knowing the geometric mean of $x$ and $y$, and knowing $c$, is not enough to determine the geometric mean of $x+c$ and $y+c$. You can produce a similar example for the harmonic mean.

Comment: @AndréNicolas you're right, it's not enough, but I thought that there was a formula, in function of the original mean, even if it had to use all the possible combinations of $x_ix_j$, and $x_ic$ and $c^{n}$ or something similar...

Comment: If there was a formula, it would have to give the same answer for $2,2,1$ as for $1,4,1$. I used integers, but if we let $a'$ and $b'$ roam over the reals with $\sqrt{a'b'}=2$, we would get infinitely many different geometric means for $a'+1$ and $b'++1$. Maybe we could get useful *bounds* on the possible geometric means.

Comment: If you are willing to use all possible combinations of $x_ix_j$ or such, then why not just compute the new geometric mean from scratch?