# Is there any mathematical relation between a harmonic mean and the harmonic mean of shifted values?

Tags: analysis, means

Let $H$ be the harmonic mean of a set of reals $x_i$.
Can we say anything about the harmonic mean $H'$ of the same set of values, but for which each value is increased by a constant $c\,$?
That is,
$$y_i = x_i + c,\quad \text{for all }i.$$

Is there any mathematical relation between $H$ and $H'\,$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182379

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for pointing me to this. The tentative answers were unfortunately not very convincing. It seems like a timid ‘no’. Is there really nothing that can be said….

Comment: I think you can prove by Jensen's inequality that $H' \geq H+c$. But I don't think there is anything more nontrivial that can be said.